How to run a private PoS blockchain?
I was trying to set my own private PoS chain based on geth. The tutorials that I have found (e.g. https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network) describe only PoA and PoW. As far as I understand the current version of geth doesn't support PoA and Pow, and anyway I wish my network would be PoS. I have read that in order to set the network I would have to set a consensus (beacon?) chain client first and connect both the consensus client and execution client (geth client) somehow... I have faced technical issues. Is there a comprehensive guide for setting up PoS (ethereum based) private network? (which describes the whole process) (I wish to understand the set up process - as I do it all for educational purposes...).
Thanks in advance for any help!


